# Intellj idea running very very slow

Tags: java

Intellj takes time to open (about 5 to 6 mins). I have deleted **pulgins** removing **files** from my laptop , but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Almost all softwares including IDEs have logs. For intellij, too. Look at following link. Get the logs. If possible enable verbose\debug log. See the time stamps if present. That should tell what task is taking too long.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files